# How to overlap two controls in iOS watch kit using interfacebuilder

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, ios-extensions

I have two button with images and i want to overlap one over another. Is it even possible to do it iOS Watch?
Moreover, how to handle background or foreground depth of a WKInterfaceObject in watch programming, like sendViewtoBackground or bringSubViewtoFront, as in normal iOS programming ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WatchOS4+**

For Watch OS4+ [follow the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46571090/684803) that @DrMickeyLauer gave.

**Outdated answer**

In the watch you don't have a Z hierarchy.

The max you can do is using a group, that has a background and then have controls over that background.

Another alternative (hack?) is to render all your hierarchy into an UIImage and set it in the watch.

Comment: Cool. Really helped me. Thanks buddy

Comment: Note that this answer has been outdated by newer versions of watchOS.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer good point, linked to your answer!

Answer (score 12):

This is possible since watchOS4: You can use groups to create *overlapping* content. Set the group's Layout attribute in the Attribute inspector to "Overlap". The system positions each item in the group based on the item's alignment attributes.

More info @ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacegroup

Comment: I created two groups with 1 image inside each group. I set them to overlay but nothing.

Comment: @tymac you have to put the 2 images on the same group that has the overlay layout..

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, using iOS normal programming.

You can have two hack:

- Create a Group, and hide the button you don't want to see. Hide/Unhide your button when you want to change.
- Manage on the same WKButton: You change the image on the button, and depending the image you modify your logic (Not a very good hack).

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to figure it out; but, I was able to not only overlap interface elements, but also set the alpha to different values. The attached images of Interface Builder show two things: overlapping objects and different alpha settings for overlapping objects.

Note the difference between the waveform.path SF Symbol in the background of Interface Controller and the play button above it. This effect cannot be achieved any other way using SF Symbols only. If the alpha of one grouped element is reduced, then the alpha for the other elements are reduced. To achieve the effect, I set the background of an overlapping group to solid black and then set the alpha to 0.75 to let about .25 of the waveform.path symbol to show through. Doing so allowed me to overlap the play button without its alpha setting being affected.

The following images show the settings for each element in the layout:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]